# output specific columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to output only 2 rows - title and sum. Title comes from orbiting_group_types table, while SUM is calculating during sql query. Here is my query that output all orbiting_group_types joined sum column:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orbiting_group_types ogt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUM (val),
        orbiting_group_type_id
    FROM
        report_orbiting_vals subrov
    WHERE
        subrov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4
    GROUP BY
        orbiting_group_type_id
) rov ON ogt. ID = rov.orbiting_group_type_id
```

I want to output only title and sum columns. How should i modify my query for that?

Comment: in which table title column is present

Comment: @JaydipJ in orbiting_group_types

Comment: Do you want to output 2 rows or 2 columns?

Comment: @lain 2 columns

Comment: @Evgeniy Then below answers should work for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT
    ogt.title,
    rov.summ 
FROM
orbiting_group_types ogt
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    SUM (val) AS summ,
    orbiting_group_type_id
  FROM
    report_orbiting_vals subrov
  WHERE
    subrov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4
 GROUP BY
    orbiting_group_type_id
) rov ON ogt. ID = rov.orbiting_group_type_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your current query works then change your select. I've also named your calculated field in the subquery

```
SELECT
    ogt.Title
    ,rov.SumValue
FROM
    orbiting_group_types ogt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUM (val) SumValue,
        orbiting_group_type_id
    FROM
        report_orbiting_vals subrov
    WHERE
        subrov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4
    GROUP BY
        orbiting_group_type_id
) rov ON ogt.ID = rov.orbiting_group_type_id
```